# Trying to conditionally set environment variables in ZSH using function

Tags: zsh

Using the following, I'm expecting the my vault provider token to be checked for existence,  if it doesn't exist it should then login before setting the environment variables.

If $proxy_auth is set to default empty string, I want to then get it from the vauilt and set it. Then, using that env variable set the others.
I have another function that sets the others to a different proxy depending on what I'm doing.

Error I'm getting is `32: condition expected: "${proxy_auth}"`

Yet to be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
export proxy_auth=""

function upenv() {
  if [[ -v VAULTTOKEN ]]
  then
    if [[ "${proxy_auth}" != '']]
    then
      export http_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTP_PROXY=$proxy_auth
      export https_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy_auth
    else
      export proxy_auth="$(getValueFromVault)"
      export http_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTP_PROXY=$proxy_auth
      export https_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy_auth
    fi
  else
    oplogin
    if [[ "${proxy_auth}" != '']]
    then
      export http_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTP_PROXY=$proxy_auth
      export https_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy_auth
    else
      export proxy_auth="$(getValueFromVault)"
      export http_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTP_PROXY=$proxy_auth
      export https_proxy=$proxy_auth
      export HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy_auth
    fi
  fi
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write everything four times. You can write the whole thing in five lines: `[[ -v VAULTTOKEN ]] || oplogin; export http_proxy="${proxy_auth:=$(getValueFromVault)}"; export HTTP_PROXY=$proxy_auth; export https_proxy=$proxy_auth; export HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy_auth`

Answer (score 0):

`if [[ "${proxy_auth}" != '']]` should have whitespace between `'` and `]`

Fix:
`if [[ "${proxy_auth}" != '' ]]`